# jQuery.get()の第１引数について

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery.get()の書き方について質問させてください。
第１引数に「URL」(パス)を書くと思いますが、
この場合パラメータ付きのURLを書くことは不可能なのでしょうか？

①$.get( "XXX.zip", function( data ) {
}　, );
この場合は、function内に処理が入ります。

②$.get( "http://XXXServlet/" + "?Id=" + Id, function( data ) {
}　, );
このようなパラメータ付きのアドレスを入力した場合、
function内に処理が入りません。
なお上記URLをブラウザのアドレス欄に入力した場合、
①の第１引数で指定したファイルのダウンロードが始まります。

後続処理のfunction内で受取ったファイルを元に処理したいのですが、
肝心の受取部分で現在躓いています。

【参考】jQuery公式サイト
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: `?` は前後どちらかの文字列に含めるか`"http://XXXServlet/?Id="` のようにする必要があると思いますがこれはタイポですか？

Comment: 申し訳ありません。タイプミスです。実際は後ろの文字列に含めており、+"?Id="のような形にしております。

Comment: 質問内容を訂正いたしました。ご教示ありがとうございます。

Comment: 参考リンク先のExamplesに存在する第2引数にデータを渡す`$.get( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );`という書き方はできないということですか？

Comment: ②を第2引数にデータを渡すように書きかえて実行しましたが、動作しませんでした。（何度も訂正申し訳ないですが、例示の都合上URLとパラメータを一部変更しました。）$.get("https://XXXX.jp:7777/XXXXServlet/xxxx.zip",{A: hensuA1,hensuA2,B: hensuB1,C:...}, function( data ) {

Comment: 取得しようとしているデータについては、xml, json, script, text, htmlではなくて、zipファイルを取得しようとしていますか？

Comment: その通りです。ZIP形式となります。それで先ほど分かったことなのですが他の方に書いた「Invalid ZIP header]のエラーメッセージについては、どうやらZIP形式の処理で利用している公開ライブラリの「jquery.zip.js」から出力されていることが分かりました。（ throw"Invalid ZIP header..";のような記載がありました）

Comment: jquery.zip‌​.jsとはjqueryの標準のAPIではないんですね？その場合は追加の環境情報になりますので、質問の編集をお願いします。前提条件が間違っていると問題解決ができません。ちなみにjQuer標準はzipファイルのAjaxによる受取はできないはずです。

Comment: jquery.zip.jsのエラーメッセージであれば、当初のjquery.get()の第１引数とは別問題でしょうから、新規に質問を起こした方がいいかと思います。

Comment: jquery.zip.jsは標準のAPIではありません。処理の中にfunction n(a) {}との関数があり、そこで固定値との比較処理が存在します。どうやらそこの判定条件に漏れてエラーとなっているようです。恐らくこれはZIP生成の方法に問題がある可能性が高いと推測し、Servlet側の調査が必要との認識です。ここまでくると当初質問とはかけ離れてると思いますので、必要に応じて新規で質問することを検討いたします。そこで本質問のクローズを考えていたのですが、上記課題がクリアされたあと上手くいくかとの検証後にしようと思いステータスとしては現状維持のままにさせていただいています。（本コミュニティのマナー違反であれば、一旦クローズします。）やり取りを通じて調査を進めて学習し初めて分かったことが多々あり、結果色々情報が後出しするような形になって申し訳ないです

Comment: Servlet側のZIP生成について、ZipFileSystemを使う方式に変更したところうまくいったようです。そのためjquery側の書き方には元々問題なく、パラメータ付きのURLでもOKという事が裏付けられました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> このようなパラメータ付きのアドレスを入力した場合、function内に処理が入りません。

`success`コールバックが呼ばれない以上、エラーが発生していると考えるのか自然です。
`jQuery.get()`に限らず、常にエラー処理を行うべきです。

またデバッグも行うべきです。今回の`jQuery.get()`であれば開発者ツールなどで、どのようなリクエストが行われ、どのようなレスポンスが得られているのか確認できるはずです。

---

コメントより

> サーブレットが実行されて「200」の結果が返ってきた。 ②コンソールタブにエラーに関する情報は出力されていない。

[jquery.getのページ](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/#jqxhr-object)には`fail`メソッドが記載されていますが、あくまでもエラー処理を行わず、質問を通じて解決策を探る方針でしょうか？ そうであればもっと情報を開示すべきです。

`"XXX.zip"`が動作するのに対し`"example.jp:7777/‌​XXXXServlet/xxxx.zip‌​"`が動作しないとすればAdditional Notesに書かれている

> - Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy); the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol.

の制約を受けている可能性も考えられますが、その場合、多くのブラウザーではコンソールにエラーメッセージが表示されます。表示されないとしたら、エラーを非表示にしている等の確認方法が間違っているかブラウザー依存の問題です。とりあえず使用されているブラウザーやアクセス先のアドレスを開示してください。

same origin policyについては[HTTP アクセス制御 (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/HTTP_access_control)も参照してください。

Comment: 開発者ツールでの確認ですが、以下の点はチェックしました。
①「$.get( XXXX, function( data ) {にブレークポイントをおき、ステップ実行をした。
ネットワークタブにて状況を確認。
XXXX部分のサーブレットが実行されて「200」の結果が返ってきた。
②コンソールタブにエラーに関する情報は出力されていない。
見方が悪いでしょうか？

Comment: getの後にfailメソッドを追加し「textStatus」「errorThrown」を確認したところ、「parse error」[Invalid ZIP header]が表示されました
このメッセージはServletで引数付のリクエストを送って、戻ってきているデータについてはZIPファイルではないとのことになるのでしょうか。（ただ直接URLをたたけば、ZIPファイルのダウンロードが始まるのですが。）

そのため試しにレスポンスを受取るMimeTypeをShift_JISから、「xhr.overrideMimeType("application/zip;");」のように変更しましたが、相変わらずエラーとなります。

#なおアドレス先は認証付きサイトの性質上開示できず申し訳ないですが、ブラウザはIE11となります。